# Typescript issue with param destructuring and null coalescing

Tags: javascript, typescript

Using parameter destructuring with null coalescing, typescript is having a issue with the optional `name` attribute. I do not want to change the original code to `const name = data?.resource?.name ?? []` which probably would make typescript happy. How can I change the typescript so it would handle the parameter destructuring with null coalescing?

code

```js
    private _getName(data: Data) {
    const { name } = data.resource ?? [];
```

type:

```js
  type Data = {
    fullUrl?: string,
    resource?: {
      active?: boolean,
      address?: Address[],
      birthDate?: string,
      gender?: string,
      id?: string,
      identifier?: Indentifier[],
      materialStatus?: Coding[],
      meta?: Security[],
      name?: Name[],
      resourceType?: string,
      telecom?: Telecom[],
    },
    search?: {
      extension?: Extension[],
      mode?: string,
      score: number,
    }
  };
```

```
error:
 error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ active?: boolean; address?: Address[]; birthDate?: string; gender?: string; id?: string; identifier?: Indentifier[]; materialStatus?: Coding[]; meta?: Security[]; name?: Name[]; resourceType?: string; telecom?: Telecom[]; } | undefined[]'.

73     const { name } = data.resource ?? []
```

Comment: data.resource is an object but you're nullish coalescing it to an array? Why?

Comment: That is equivalent to `const name = (data.resource ?? []).name`. And arrays do not have a `name` property, so you get this error. What do expect `name` to be when `data.resource` is `undefined`?

Comment: e.g. [here it is with no error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATAuE8AcFNgEQIagcAvMA3gKBCATtAM4D2ArngMbQD8AXJjriAHYIC2N9hoeAlswHMA2gF0ANIxABfCdIDcWRgDNSzCqF7FmwJcWIAKACb1EyAJQMmFLd0zBWHNMFHApTwwDoCJclWDVqTClGYKA). Did you maybe mean `const { name = [] } = data.resource ?? {};`

Comment: @JaredSmith I have ` const nameData = name.find((el) => el.use === 'usual');`in. In JS, this coalescing to array works for me.

Comment: No offense, but I'm having a hard time believing that. Alex Wayne is correct about the semantics, and they are not different between TS and JS here. Please post a minimal reproducible example, otherwise I'm going to have to vote to close this as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
const data: { resource?: { name?: string } } = {}
const name = data?.resource?.name ?? []
console.log(name) // []
```

And this:

```
const data: { resource?: { name?: string } } = {}
const { name } = data.resource ?? []; // type error
console.log(name) // undefined
```

Are *not* logically equivalent.

The first one resolves to an array when `data.resource` is `undefined`. So `const name` is assigned a value of `[]`.

The second one expects whatever is on the right hand side of the `=` to have a `name` property, and the value of that `name` property will be assigned to `const name`.

But an array does not have a `name` property, so you get a type error, and at runtime would be `undefined`.

---

In order to make this work with destructuring you must make sure whatever is on the right side here has a `name` property.

For example:

```
const { name } = data.resource ?? { name: [] };
```

But that's pretty silly.

I think that this:

```
const name = data?.resource?.name ?? []
```

Is the cleanest solution here. It's not advisable to use destructuring assignment unless all possible values being destructured support the property being destructured.

[See Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggXDA3jATgUwiAVy2BwH41MwEBbMtaLASzAHMYBfDmAXg3YCh+6fjFExQkWFVo94SBKQB0ufERJLpOGKVIwA2gF0RYifgA2ORWZAsAFAHJTUmlt6JkSlYWJlFm7bqG9gA0MJoAlDAA9FH6RgJCxqJOGGEuXG7yynjeJAFxANzRsVAAngAOWjhYWCBYSeLg5pbWdo5NsJTpnJnI2ao++UGhEcUwBGBwOABmzDhw-AnCYo2Sqf49cn1ealo66y5ohhwFDaYgFlY2DildMpvuCP25e7p3OEcGHCFptJExcUWQA). Click "Run" and see the console output for yourself.